# Python: How to Apply Style on Pandas Dataframe by Comparing Two Values on the Same Column but on the Different Rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, python-applymap

Suppose that we have this dataframe:

| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 5 | 10 |

How to apply color if values on the same column is equals but skip the first column?
In my case, column **Value 2** must be colored

I have used Pandas df.apply, but the example is compare column on the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi, you can try like this one:**

```
df = df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color: lightgreen']*len(df) if (x.iloc[0] == x.iloc[1] and x.name != 'Value1') else ['background-color: white']*len(df), axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def color(s):
    return s.duplicated(keep=False).map({True: 'background-color: yellow'})

df.style.apply(color, subset=df.columns[1:], axis=0)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(np.ones(len(x), dtype=bool) * x.nunique() == 1, 
              'background-color: yellow', ''), 
               subset=df.columns[1:], 
               axis=0)
```

Comment: @yunastrian - Are you sure solution is correct? First column is always `Value 1` ? DataFrame has always 2 rows?

Comment: Yes it solve my problem. My dataframe has always 2 rows, And I rename the column name "Value 1" to the right column nime